# How to create a public id?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database. As you can see the primary key is an `auto_increment` and is also unique. I read that publically sharing a row's primary key of a table to the public is unsafe. I want to assign each row in `customers` a unique ID that I can publically share. How can I do this without having to specify each time what the public_id is in the `INSERT` statement? The database should automatically find a unique ID to assign to that row just like it does for `id` because of `auto_increment`.

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
id int primary key auto_increment,
name varchar(32) not null,
-- public_id (an ID I can give to the public to uniquely identify this row
);

INSERT INTO customers (name) VALUES ('Bob'), ('Sarah'), ('Bob');
```

Comment: `I read that publically sharing a row's primary key of a table to the public is unsafe.`...depends on the circumstances

Comment: @ADyson What type of circumstances?

Comment: The thing with sequential IDs is that people can reliably guess them. If you got an ID of `1234`, then you can be reasonably sure that `1233` also exists, and maybe even `1235`, etc. You can try out a bunch of different numbers and see what you can get. If your system has proper security in place (like, nobody can see what they shouldn't see even if they guess the ID), then maybe you are safe. Although a sequential ID would also allow one to see approximately how many rows you have in your table (like, how many customers). Is that a problem for you? Etc. You be the judge.

Comment: Thank you Vix for that response. That make sense. In that case, then it seems `UUID()` is a safe bet

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov - Fairly so, yes, however, as the manual stated, `they are not necessarily unguessable or unpredictable`. In practice what this means is that it will probably be very hard to guess them, but not _impossible_. It does rely on some random numbers, but those numbers are only "pseudo-random". If you know enough of them in a row (and the algorithm for generating them), you can begin to guess what the next ones will be. Granted, this will be difficult to pull off, but a very determined attacker might be able to do it. I think it was Wordpress that once fell afoul of something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's one way:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(32) not null,
    public_id char(36) not null unique default uuid()
);
```

Note that the manual says:

> ### Warning
>
> Although UUID() values are intended to be unique, they are not necessarily unguessable or unpredictable. If unpredictability is required, UUID values should be generated some other way.

So this is simple, and maybe will float your goat, but we can also try better:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(32) not null,
    public_id char(24) not null unique default to_base64(random_bytes(18))
);
```

This will be a nice and dense identifier, but it will have characters `+` and `/` which don't play well with URLs. You can encode them, of course, but if you want to go one lazier, you can also do this:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(32) not null,
    public_id char(32) not null unique default hex(random_bytes(16))
);
```

Mind you, the identifier will get quite a bit longer this way.

To get the best of both worlds, we can do this, at the expense of a really long default value:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(32) not null,
    public_id char(24) not null unique default replace(replace(to_base64(random_bytes(18)), '+', '_'), '/', '-')
);
```

Also note that messing around with `MD5()`/`SHA()`/`SHA1()`/`SHA2()` is no better than just generating a random hex string with a given length.

Comment: If I use UUID and do a bulk insert, wouldn't I get an error? I also ready UUID works based on space and time. So if I did a bulk insert (like the one in my post), I will get 3 identical UUID's? Hence causing an error?

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov - You shouldn't. But do test these options, I just wrote them here without trying them out for real. If there are any issues, please report them here, so I can edit my answer.